# sort or unique command bash

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

This is a file . I want to remove the repetition in the name of patch

```
[ppande@server-1 —]$egrep 'Patch[0-9].*.*:' content1
Patch1001 : snmp fixl.org
Patch1002 : dhcp tmp fix
Patch1003 : qemu-img-9.0.58
Patch001 : snmp fixl.org
Patch002 : dhcp installation
Patch003 : qemu
Patch004 : snmp fixl.org
```

I used 'sort -u' but here the order of the patch is changed . All I need is the output with out repetitions and order remains same , or in other words if there is a repetition the second/last occurrence must not be displayed .

```
[ppande@server-1 —]$egrep 'Patch[0-9].*.*:' content1 | sort -u -k3
Patch002 : dhcp installation
Patch1002 : dhcp tmp fix
Patch003 : qemu
Patch1003 : qemu-img-0.0.58
Patch1001 : snmp fixl.org
Patch001 : snmp fixl.org
```

Desired output:

```
Patch1001 : snmp fixl.org
Patch1002 : dhcp tmp fix
Patch1003 : qemu-img-9.0.58
Patch002 : dhcp installation
Patch003 : qemu
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Desired Output:

Patch1001 : snmp fixl.org
Patch1002 : dhcp tmp fix
Patch1003 : qemu-img-9.0.58
Patch002 : dhcp installation
Patch003 : qemu

Comment: Check file content1 for trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since oguzismail added same solution few secs before me so adding perl solution now if you are ok with it.

```
perl -aF': ' -lne 'print if ! $seen{$F[1]}++'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. You need not to use multiple commands along with `awk` here.

```
awk -F': '  '/Patch[0-9].*.*/ && !a[$2]++'  Input_file
```

Comment: Ravinder , this Perl oneliner wont work as I tried it make more noise of unwanted lines those that have a string followed by colon . The lines with 'Patch[[:digit:]]:' is fetched but few more lines with '<string>:' is also displayed .

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a single awk command.

```
awk -F ':\\s*' '/^Patch[0-9]+\s*:/ && !a[$2]++' content1
```

Comment: Added a one liner perl solution now, based on same kind of logic though.